# Provide layout_height and layout_width from strings.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-imageview

I'm trying to set `ImageView`'s height and width from constant string from `strings.xml` as following:

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/GetMailing"
            android:layout_width="@string/continueBtnWidthHD"
            android:layout_height="@string/continueBtnHeightHD"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/continue_button_style" />
```

and in `strings.xml`, I have:

```
<string name="continueBtnHeightHD">60dp</string>
<string name="continueBtnWidthHD">250dp</string>
```

But this gives error while executing `setContentView(view_Id)`.

Error is **java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #82: You must supply a layout_width attribute.**

I'm using this approach as I want to use same values at various places.

This is bit strange as I'm using same approach to set `maxlength` of `EditText` and it's working fine.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of providing "string" as resource, you provide it "dimen" as:

**In dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="continueBtnHeightHD">60dp</dimen>
<dimen name="continueBtnWidthHD">250dp</dimen>
```

**In activity xml file**

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/GetMailing"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/continueBtnWidthHD"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/continueBtnHeightHD"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/continue_button_style" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Height and Width are meant to be used as below

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="my_dimen">10dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

and now, Use above attributes in your layout file like this

```
 android:layout_width="@dimens/my_dimen"
 android:layout_height="@dimens/my_dimen"
```

You can use `@dimen/mydimen` with any view and whenever you needs to hardcode `dp` in a Layout file.

Answer (score 3):

Don't put these in strings.xml, put them in `dimens.xml` as dimensions:

```
<dimen name="continueBtnHeightHD">60dp</dimen>
<dimen name="continueBtnWidthHD">250dp</dimen>
```

And then in the layout.xml:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/GetMailing"
            android:layout_width="@dimens/continueBtnWidthHD"
            android:layout_height="@dimens/continueBtnHeightHD"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/continue_button_style" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use file dimens.xml and not strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<dimen name="continueBtnHeightHD">60dp</dimen>
<dimen name="continueBtnWidthHD">250dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then in your layout, you reference these values in this way:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/GetMailing"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/continueBtnWidthHD"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/continueBtnHeightHD"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/continue_button_style" />
```

Comment: android:layout_width="@dimens or android:layout_width="@dimen ?

Comment: @MohammadAfrashteh of course it's `dimen`. Typo fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Create size.xml inside values folder as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<dimen name="continueBtnHeightHD">60dp</dimen>
<dimen name="continueBtnWidthHD">250dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Inside your layout.xml

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/GetMailing"
            android:layout_width="@dimens/continueBtnWidthHD"
            android:layout_height="@dimens/continueBtnHeightHD"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/continue_button_style" />
```

Comment: android:layout_width="@dimens

or

android:layout_width="@dimen

?

Answer (score 2):

This is an incorrect use of string resources. You should be using the [Dimension](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) for specifying the dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using strings resources for this, you should use dimension resources. See here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

You can create a file dimens.xml inside your values folder (the same place you put the strings.xml).

Example dimens.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <dimen name="continueBtnHeightHD">60dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="continueBtnWidthHD">250dp</dimen>
</resources>
```